# Can't create ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application using Visual Studio 2015 update 3

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have just installed the `asp.net` core template pack for visual studio 2015 Update 3. I did it both by using the `.visz` file and by Visual Studio 2015 >> Tools >> Select Extensions and Updates.

In each case it seemed to install without any problems.

However I cannot create an ASP.NET Core Angular 2 Starter Application. Each time I try I receive the following error message:
[Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbNtt.jpg)

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

The error message is valid, that file (actually the whole DotNet folder) does not exist on disk.

Has anyone encountered this and successfully resolved it?

Comment: You are supposed to use Visual Studio 2017 or VSCode for .NET Core projects.

Comment: please see my comment below.

Comment: claiming « all you have » is VS2015 is useless, as .NET Core is not officially supported there. Escalate to your manager and that’s what you should do now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create ASP.NET Core Angular project using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 as there is no support for that template and ASP.NET Core version greater than 1.1 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. You must have to install Visual Studio 2017 to use ASP.NET Core Angular template.

Comment: The template is specifically for VS 2015 Update 3. I followed the instructions exactly as described in this article - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Core-Template-Pack-71bcde34. Also here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-template-pack/.

Comment: Oh! got it! this is third party template. Look at here is ASP.NET Core version is 1.0..Why are you wanting Project on ASP.NET Core version 1.0 while current stable version is 2.1.

Comment: I'm learning development with Angular 2 and ASP.NET Core. It's not my area of expertise.  I just wanted to complete the article for learning purposes.

Comment: Additionally I use Visual Studio 2015 in the workplace. It's all I have access to.

Comment: As you are learning then what's wrong to use Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their assistance, although there seemed to be more questions than answers provided.

I'll just install VS 2017 and learn from that.